# Submitting App to Google Play store guidelines

Tags: android, google-play

I am preparing myself to submit my first app to the Google Play Store, and have the following questions regarding the process, which might have been covered or not covered before, so I apologize if there are any duplicates beforehand, because I could not understand some of them.

1. In submission of an app to the Play Store, what is the expected time duration which it will get accepted or rejected?
2. Because I do not live in an area where Google Payments is accessible, what are the payment schemes that I can get for my app?
3. Is it possible to submit a complete rewrite of the same app as an update at a later date? If so, is there a specific method (e.g. signing schemes)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Sure. I will do so.

Answer (score 2):

From my experiences to avoid rejection or suspension do not put copyright protected contents on your apps and store listing.
Do not make apps that having harmful behavior.

If you collect user data make sure you have a well documented privacy policy.

Try to avoid spam words for your app name  (like flappy,candy crush, clash of clans etc.. Avoid these words)

Avoid putting ads against their policy

Be clear with the UI. Don't confuse user with UI elements that leads to any kind of promotional contents without proper description.

App approval time may vary according to their job loads and types of app you are submitting, Apps now go through both machine and human verification, usually games get faster approval than apps. Average time I feel is around 4 - 5 hours for initial launch, updates get faster approval.

They give enough time to repair the problems. 
App Rejections are easier to get through but App suspension are difficult.
It is hard to win a dispute with Google :)
Especially if you get a copyright issues you can't even pass machine verification and can't argue with algorithms ;)

Now it's much more easier because they have human verification too. They point out most of the problems. Before that it was a total mess. They reply with some pre generated generic replys

Good luck with your venture.

Comment: Thank you very much